# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Datatables()

Tags: laravel, datatable

I already install yajra package but it still show me error

my controller and i also used namespace

```
use Datatables;

return Datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
```

my providers

```
Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
```

'aliases'

```
'Datatables'=>Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it with a helper and you don't have to include it. You accessed the class of datatables, not the helper. Do it like this.

```
return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
```

Comment: getting error "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\datatables()", any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yajra namespace is Yajra\DataTables. so you need to call it as below.

```
use Yajra\DataTables\Datatables;
```

or if you want to call only `use Datatables` then you need to set providers and alias.

**config/app.php**

```
.....
'providers' => [
    ....
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
]
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]
.....
```

And then you can use simply

```
use DataTables;
```

Comment: already set provider and alias check my updated question

Comment: There is a mistake in alias check.. n don't forget to clear the cache.. php artisan config: cache

Comment: if i changed provider acording to you then it shows me   "Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider' not found  "

Comment: any one who will help me out